# Are there any GOOD iPhone orms?

Tags: iphone, orm

I'm traditionally a .NET developer and am spoiled for choice when it comes to ORMs. My flavor of choice is NHibernate but there are a bunch of choices out there.

I was wondering if anyone here uses an ORM when developing for the iPhone and, if so, how do the feature sets compare with that of it's Java and .NET counterparts. I understand my question is somewhat subjective (good can encompass many things) but feature-richness, ease-of-use and performance are my key interests. I know that there are a few out there, but would like to hear from the StackOverflow community in terms of how good they are...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think that [Core Data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_Data) is the ORM of choice for almost all iPhone developers.  It's fast, easy to use, and well integrated with the rest of Cocoa.

Comment: Ya now that Core Data is available it is the best option by far in terms of performance and efficiency

Answer (score 3):

Apple's own [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/macosx/coredata.html) is probably a good choice as it integrates seamlesly with the rest of the SDK.

- [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html)
- [Data Modeling Guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataModeling/index.html)
- [Core Data Reference for Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreData_ObjC/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're going to roll your own special purpose ORM I'd probably stick with CoreData, although I've heard some good things about [SQLite Persistent Objects](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/08/sqlite-persistent-objects.html), it's been compared to RoR's ActiveRecord (keep in mind I've never used it myself, I only added here because I've heard a few colleagues talk about it).